# Cache inconsistency caused by different db writes

Tags: caching, consistency

If i have an object "Car" with three attributes, 
`{
  year: "2016-12-01",
  make: "toyota",
  model: "camry"
}`, and there are three tables in db with each field as its primary key,
table 1: `year(key), make, model`
table 2: `make(key), model, year`
table 3: `model(key), make, year`, 
of which, read and write to each table is handled by different services A, B, C.

Let's say A, B, C each did a read once, and put the Car info in cache, so
A has `year => {make, model}`
B has `make => {model, year}`
C has `model => {make, year}`,

then B updated the year to `"2016-12-25"`, so such element in B's cache would be deleted after a db write, but what about the other two? How do we make sure the other two caches also delete the corresponding elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two options: either synchronize the delete operations or not.

- If you require deletes to be processed immediately in the other caches, you will need to synchronize the operation by sending delete requests to the caches.
- If you can tolerate some delay in it being deleted/refreshed, maybe it's enough to just update the database and wait for the cache entries to expire on the other services.

The requirements depend a lot if your services function correctly seeing ghost cars or not.

A relevant article is [’Cause I’m Strong Enough:
Reasoning about Consistency Choices in Distributed Systems](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/hongseok.yang/paper/popl16b-submitted.pdf), from Alexey Gotsman, Hongseok Yang, Carla Ferreira, Mahsa Najafzadeh, and Marc Shapiro.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.